# updating let's encrypt with certbot not working

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

I am trying to update a recently expired cert using certbot (the original cert was also generated via certbot).  However, the update command is not working:

```
sudo ./certbot-auto renew --quiet --no-self-upgrade
Use of --agree-dev-preview is deprecated.
Use of --agree-dev-preview is deprecated.
Attempting to renew cert from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/www.removed.com.conf produced an unexpected error: <Response [404]>. Skipping.
Attempting to renew cert from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/www.removed.com-0001.conf produced an unexpected error: <Response [404]>. Skipping.
Attempting to renew cert from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/removed.com.conf produced an unexpected error: <Response [404]>. Skipping.

All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.removed.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.removed.com-0001/fullchain.pem (failure)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/removed.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
```

The certbot log has the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/test/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 861, in main
    args = cli.prepare_and_parse_args(plugins, cli_args)
  File "/home/test/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/cli.py", line 1074, in prepare_and_parse_args
    return helpful.parse_args()
  File "/home/test/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/cli.py", line 551, in parse_args
    self.set_test_server(parsed_args)
  File "/home/test/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/cli.py", line 568, in set_test_server
    " and ".join(conflicts)))
Error: --server value conflicts with --dry-run
```

Any ideas on fixing this issue?  I have tried running the above renew command as root.  I have stopped nginx in case it was interfering with the process.

Comment: Looks like you're just getting a `404` error when trying to send a request to the server. Have you tried waiting a few hours to try again in case this is a server side problem? Has the update worked in the past?

Comment: I have tried the update on more than one day - will check firewall

Comment: the firewall settings were not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code of the newer versions of certbot that make use of the ACME-v02 API (the one that supports wildcard certificates), it seems that for --dry-run option the only accepted server value is the new staging endpoint

```
...        
def set_test_server(self, parsed_args):
    """We have --staging/--dry-run; perform sanity check and set config.server"""

    if parsed_args.server not in (flag_default("server"), constants.STAGING_URI):
        conflicts = ["--staging"] if parsed_args.staging else []
        conflicts += ["--dry-run"] if parsed_args.dry_run else []
        raise errors.Error("--server value conflicts with {0}".format(
            " and ".join(conflicts)))

        parsed_args.server = constants.STAGING_URI
...
```

And the code of constants.py file

```
...
STAGING_URI = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
...
```

So theoretically to solve the problem you could either:

1. Specify that staging server endpoint
2. Create/edit /etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini and include the server option there instead of specifying it in the command
3. Create a config file wherever you want with the valid server option value and pass it to the command as --config /path/yourconfig.ini or -c /path/yourconfig.ini

LINKS:

- https://github.com/certbot/certbot/blob/v0.23.0/certbot/cli.py
- https://github.com/certbot/certbot/blob/v0.23.0/certbot/constants.py
- https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#configuration-file
- https://www.eigenmagic.com/2018/03/14/howto-use-certbot-with-lets-encrypt-wildcard-certificates/ (see Winston's comment in the end)

P.S.: I say theoretically because non of those worked for me

Comment: i believe the issue was caused by the web server being misconfigured (not handling the lets encrypt url)